# How to interact with Docker daemon directly (bypass the terminal) through Java program

Tags: java, docker, containers

User types docker command in terminal, and terminal sends it to Docker daemon, and then receives the response from Docker daemon and display it to user.

Is it possible that we develop a Java program to do the things what terminal does, directly talking to Docker daemon? 
If it is possible we can add some custom functionalities to Docker by developing in this Java program.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at those: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api/. Docker provides a remote API via unix sockets. For java you could use any library with that support. For example: https://github.com/mcfunley/juds or https://github.com/kohlschutter/junixsocket.